# how do I show/hide a youtube video using jquery without losing current state?

Tags: jquery, youtube-api

I'm building a jquery ajax page that shows a list of youtube videos. I've got two views on the page (list & video), which are built as LI elements, floated left, inside a UL element. I built it this way because the transition between the views is done using a horizontal slide effect and I found that using the list allows the page to vertically resize correctly when the height of the views are different.

When a video is selected from the list view, I first see if it exists inside the DOM. If it does, I simply move it to the video view. If not, I create a new DIV and load the video into it. Once the video is moved into the video view, I slide the video view into place. When transitioning back to the list view, I move the video into a hidden "helper" div so I can keep it in the DOM.

The problem I'm having is that the youtube player gets reset whenever I move it to/from the video view. So even if a video has been completely loaded (and/or partially played), after moving it, the player resets back to 0 and has to completely reload. I'm using appendTo() to move it around.

Here's a simplified jsfiddle test:

http://jsfiddle.net/UPhek/3/

You'll see in my test code that I can show/hide a player and keep the state. But when I use .appendTo() to move the video DIV into a helper DIV, I lose the state of the player. I setup 3 tests... you can change the test by changing the whichTest global variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the video's visibility:

```
visiblity: hidden
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UPhek/4/

Tou can append this item to the "video view" side, if it hasn't been loaded already, and then change it's visiblity, preferably with a css class.

---

You could use this in conjunction with the YouTube API and stop/start videos with javascript:

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
video.pauseVideo();
```

You'll probably have to switch from an `iframe` to an `embed` tag

---

Also, the [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) javascript library is always good when working with Flash

Comment: See also "display: none" CSS instead of modifying the visibility property, in case you don't want the video element to take up space.

Comment: Thanks... I'll try the embed version again. I will need to start/stop after hiding, so (I think) I need to use the embed version in order to access the JS API.

Comment: Setting visibility to "hidden" works in terms of keeping the state of the player, but it will also take up space in the window. This might be because my video DIV is set to float left. I set the video DIV to have a width and height of 0 and a margin-top of -10000, seems to hide it.

Answer (score 0):

Appending an element isn't the same as *moving* it. I haven't dove into the jQuery source for this answer but I'm pretty sure that what happens when you take an element and append it somewhere else, it's merely copying the original node, destroying it, then inserting the copy into the new location. This will destroy the state of your video.

Hunter has the answer you're looking for. By hiding the video and using the youtube api to stop it, you're effectively accomplishing your goal.

Comment: Interesting... also the player resets when using jquery .show() and .hide() - http://jsfiddle.net/UPhek/10/